# Creating Dictionary of first letter from list of words from txt file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a txt file with a list of words. I want to take those words and create a dictionary with using the first letter as the key and then appending the words that start with that letter.  This is what I have so far...

```
file = open('words.txt').read()
print(file)
```

the result of the file:
["aback","abaft","abandoned","abashed","aberrant","abhorrent","abiding","abject","ablaze","able","abnormal","aboard","aboriginal","abortive","abounding","abrasive","abrupt","absent","absorbed","absorbing","abstracted","absurd","abundant","abusive","acceptable","accessible", ....]

```
alphaDict = {}

for word in file:
    if word[0] not in alphaDict.keys():
        alphaDict[word[0]] = []
        alphaDict[word[0]].append(word)
    else:
        alphaDict[word[0]].append(word)

for k,v in alphaDict.items():
    print(k , ":", v)
```

What am I missing?  This is the result I get.
[ : ['[']
" : ['"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"',

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks like a *json* file containing the list of words. You should to `json.load()` to deserialize it into a python list before iterating `for word in file`:

```
import json
with open("words.txt") as f:
    words = json.load(f)
```

I renamed file to words, because your variable names should indicate what they are

Also, you don't need the `else:`, because you want to append to the list regardless of whether it existed before this iteration or you created it in this iteration:

```
alphaDict = {}

for word in file:
    if word[0] not in alphaDict: # In py3, don't need to do .keys()
        alphaDict[word[0]] = []
        
    alphaDict[word[0]].append(word)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but how did you know the file was json? the contents didn't have any {}.   Why didn't the open method work?

Comment: A json file doesn't have to have `{}`. Braces represent _objects_ in json (or dicts when deserialized in python). `[]` represent lists.

Comment: If your file contained just the words and no extra characters, you'd have been able to read in the file using `.read()`, **split it up into individual words** (which you forgot to do), and iterate on that list. But since you forgot to split it up, `file` is a _string_, not a list, and doing `for word in file` iterates character-by-character over the string. Step through in a debugger to see what exactly happens